# What is cumin good for?

Tags: flavor

I would like input from anyone that uses cumin in their food. I inherited a jar of the seasoning when my mom moved out of state. Better to give it away than throw it away. Unfortunately, I have no clue what to do with it. I've had this jar for a while. And I'd like to use it before it goes bad.

I was wondering what it's used for?

Comment: https://www.thekitchn.com/inside-the-spice-cabinet-cumin-67449

Comment: Seeds or ground? Cumin loses flavors fast after you grind it up. Fried cumin powder is essential to store bought refried beans. Gives you about 70% of home cooked flavor.

Answer (score 8):

Cumin is the spice that, to me, makes taco meat taste like taco meat.  Whenever I make ground beef tacos I use lots of it.  It also tastes really good with sautéed potatoes.

Answer (score 8):

Any number of different cuisines have cumin as a base spice.
Anything from Tex/Mex to Arabian to Indian. It's also used in plenty of Italian and Chinese dishes, just not quite as much.

Comment: wow, i've learned the secret to a childhood favorite. and now my mind is blown with new ideas. i appreciate your comments. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's also incredibly good in Mujadara, a Middle Eastern dish of lentils and rice.  I'm assuming it's whole cumin, though, that you'll grind yourself; if it's preground, it may well have already lost its flavor.